# time complexity of a simple python program

Tags: python, time-complexity

```
def foo(n):
    for i in range(n):
        for k in range(1,i):
            if k>n/k:
                return k
```

what is the time complexity of this program?
answer says its O(n). any explanations for that would be welcome

edit: typo

Comment: Start python and enter `len(range(1,1))`, `len(range(100,100))`, and `len(range(10000,10000))`. Notice how wide each interval is.

Answer (score 3):

> answer says its O(n).

Yes, the complexity is `O(N)` because

```
for k in range(i,i)
```

`for` *loop* is never executed.

So, your code is equivalent to

```
def foo(n):
    for i in range(n):
       pass
```

**UPDATE**

```
def foo(n):
    for i in range(n):
        for k in range(1,i):
            if k>n/k:
                return k
```

`k>n/k` is equivalent to `k^2 > n` and it's `k > sqrt(n)`

The main *loop* is mainly executed `sqrt(n)` times and the inner *loop* is executed *0 times*, then *1 times*, then *2 times*, ..... , *sqrt(n) times* before it returns from the function.

So, the total complexity is `O(sqrt(n) * sqrt(n))` which is `O(n)`

Comment: my bad. it was a typo. its (1,i) not (i,i)